# Running script on Windows XP shutdown/reboot

Tags: windows-xp, scripting

I have been looking for a way to run a batch script(just a single 'del' command) whenever the system shutdowns or reboots. The system is running a Windows XP Professional with Service Pack 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a shutdown script from within the group policy editor (Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts).

Comment: +1. I use the startup/shutdown script on all servers (via GPO) to have an email sent when a machine is shutting down, and has then booted back up, on top of monitoring, just in case the reboot is too quick for Nagios to catch it. Handy. (Although I'd love it if it didn't matter which servers were shut down :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use scheduled tasks to run a command at system start or user log on. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569

Comment: Does not cover shutdown/logoff.

Comment: But can be combined with the other approach.